# Angular Differentiating keydown.enter for textarea in mobile vs desktop

Tags: angular, chat, enter

I'm currently developing a chat platform, with a message input box using textarea (where the user types his/her message). Pressing the Enter key allows the user to send a message. However, I would like to know if it's possible to differentiate the Enter key behavior for desktop view and mobile view, like so -

If user presses the enter key in the textarea field:
1. Desktop view: user is able to send the message
2. Mobile view: a new line is created in the textarea field, message is not sent

**message.component.html**

```
<textarea autosize [minRows]="1" [maxRows]="10" [(ngModel)]="messageToSend"
    (keydown.enter)="sendMessage($event)" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
```

**message.component.ts**

```
sendMessage(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const message: Message = {
      id: this.id,
      date: new Date(),
      body: this.message,
    };
    this.chatService.sendChatMessage(id, message).subscribe();
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check screen size then you can try [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 768px)').matches) {
   console.log('Screen is less then 768')
}
```